# Why am I getting this error in my rails solidus app after installing bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass, solidus

I am trying to set up a solidus app with custom css using bootstrap-sass. (I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFalBLRMgdI&list=PLjQo0sojbbxWv_k3FGWpTrCOcqXU_ZhDs&index=2) tutorial)

Prior to getting this error, the page would load just fine but none of the bootstrap css would load correctly. This error started after I added

```
#= require bootstrap_sprockets
#= require_tree
```

to my `all.coffee` file

and adding

```
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

to my `Gemfile`

the complete `all.sass` file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

the complete `all.coffee` file:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require spree
#= require bootstrap_sprockets
#= require_tree
```

the complete `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sassc-rails'

gem 'solidus'
gem 'solidus_auth_devise'
gem 'deface'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

when I run the server I get the following error:

```
Error: Function very-light finished without @return
        on line 38:34 of ../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/solidus_backend-2.2.2/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/globals/_variables.scss, in function `very-light`
        from line 38:34 of ../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/solidus_backend-2.2.2/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/globals/_variables.scss
        from line 6:9 of ../../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/solidus_backend-2.2.2/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/spree_admin.scss
>> $color-border:                   very-light($color-3, 12) !default;
```

I'm not sure what exactly I need to do to fix this. I've made sure that I have the required gems for bootstrap-sass in my Gemfile and I've tried running `bundle update`.

Answer (score 2):

the latest sassc-rails gem implemented via sassc, wich requires all CSS functions should ensure that they do not end without a `@return` statement.

and solidus fix it after v2.9, you can see it on https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/commit/aeba736e742eaf39e45b294433e33d663ac66f24